# Sqlite replace() for replacing multiple characters

Tags: android, sqlite

I have database table Contacts with columns `Mobile`, `officePhone`.

Here users will save data as follows.

```
mobile=+91 (937) 2582 6433
officephone= (843)-6486-6783
```

Now i need to retrieve phone numbers with out any special characters

Some how i found following query,

```
Select REPLACE(mobile,'+','') as mobile , REPLACE(officePhone,'+','') as officePhone from Contacts;
```

This will remove only "+" symbol but i want to remove all special symbols including space.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: why don't you replace them using java once you have retrieved them from the database in their original form.

Comment: true dat. Just get the full numbers and do a replace in java code. Loop through each char and check if its not numeric then replace it

Comment: This seems a good idea. Let me try, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove special characters before inserting or selecting from the database like below

```
String number = removeSpecialCharacters("+91 (937) 2582 6433");
System.out.println("number::::"+number.trim().replace(" ", ""));
String number1 = removeSpecialCharacters("(843)-6486-6783");
System.out.println("number1::::"+number1.trim().replace(" ", ""));

public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String string) {
   StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++) {
        char character = string.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(character) || Character.isSpaceChar(character))
            sbuffer.append(character);
    }
    return sbuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly pretty, but you could nest the replace() functions:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(mobile,' ',''),'-',''),'(',''),')','')
```

Agreed, if possible you can format outside of sqlite, but that is not always wanted/possible. E.g. I had a case where the replaces were needed for the WHERE part.